# Output a list in using Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am teaching myself Kotlin and Android app development.  I am running into a small issue trying to print a list using reduce.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val findBeer = findViewById<Button>(R.id.find_beer)
        findBeer.setOnClickListener{
             val beerColor = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.beer_color)
             val color = beerColor.selectedItem.toString()

             val beerlist = getBeers(color.toString())

             val beers = beerlist.reduce{ str, item -> str + '/n' + item }

             val brands = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.brands);
             brands.text = beerlist.toString()
    }

}

    fun getBeers(color: String): List<string> {
        return when (color) {
            "Light" -> listOf("Jail Pale Ale", "Lage Lite")
            "Amber" -> listOf("Jack Amber", "Red Moose")
            "Brown" -> listOf("Brown Bear Beer", "Bock Brownie")
            else -> listOf("Gout Stout", "Dark Daniel")
        }
    }
```

Android Studio is giving me  None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch error.

Comment: List<string>  the S needs to be capital and '/n' needs to be in "/n" for it to work otherwise it would give you compilation errors.

Comment: `'\n'` (backslash not forward slash) works fine as a `Char` since it represents the newline character, but yeah if you use a forward slash it needs to be a `String` (double quotes) since `/n` counts as two characters

Comment: Thank you.  Both suggestions worked.